# Using MySQLi and ArrayObjects to output Data

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, arrayobject

This is less of a question and more a learning path for me when using MySQLi and ArrayObjects.  If this is old hat for you, please feel free to add any additional improvements to the following.  If new to MySQLi and ArrayObject, this is a short example of the whole process.  Which is FAR more efficient then the procedural style.

The Query:

```
//constants for mysqli credentials, DB_HOST,DB_UNAME etc.
include('dbase');

//zip code to seach
$zipcode = 10003;

//instantiate the object variable
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_UNAME,DB_UPWORD,DB_NAME);

//run the query searching for matching records using a regular expression
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT corg_id, corg_name, corg_city FROM sometable WHERE corg_zip REGEXP '^$zipcode';");

//using fetch_object() returns an ArrayObject
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
       $zipmatch[] = $row;
}

//assign to session var for later use, in another script
$_SESSION['queryresult'] = $zipmatch;
```

So at this point the query returned a result.  The resulting ArrayObject looks like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [corg_id] => 1
        [corg_name] => Acme Home Improvement
        [corg_city] => New York
    )

   [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [corg_id] => 2
        [corg_name] => ABC Handy Work
        [corg_city] => New York
    )

   [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [corg_id] => 3
        [corg_name] => Wile E Coyote Repairs
        [corg_city] => New York
    )
)
```

The Output:
Lets say we want one record from the data slice above.  Since this is an array object, some looping constructs will return errors because they expect strings and not object references. foreach will take an object reference or an array.

```
function selected($arrObject,$searchString,$result){
    foreach($arrObject as $v){
       if ($v->corg_id==$searchString){
        $result[] = $v->corg_name; //string, would be index 0
        $result[] = $v->corg_city; //string, would be index 1
       }
    }     
    return $result;
  } //close selected function

$result = array(); //array of returned search data
$haystack = $_SESSION['queryresult']; //arrayObject to search
$needle = 3; //look for a matching id in the arrayObject

//instantiate an output array with the result of the selected function
$outputArray=selected($haystack,$needle,$result);
   $comName = $outputArray[0]; //string
   $comCity = $outputArray[1]; //string

echo $comName; //outputs "Wile E Coyote Repairs"
echo $comCity; //outputs "New York"
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

So what is it you "like" to improve?

I could swap the whole PHP search method etc for one single SQL query

```
SELECT corg_name, corg_city FROM sometable WHERE corg_id = '$corg_id';
```

Would be a lot easier instead of searching an entire array in PHP, if you can easily return just one result by selecting on the ID in the SQL database.

Comment: That's true, but assuming the user has two search requirements, one would be all the resulting businesses in some zipcode, then a second search where it was one business in the resulting zipcodes search.

Comment: If the requirement is "one" business in the second search, then the logic I described above doesn't change. It depends on this PHP search if you want to "relief" the SQL database from any traffic, if so it might be a good solution to search in PHP, else I would always prefer searching for results in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good comments.  In this instance the user only knows a zip code.  If the query returns a result, they can then select a business to get additional information.  You could make two trips to the database; or in this example, one trip and one array search.  If the business was known by some variable, then your approach in the right one.

Comment: I would advice that any down voter leaves a comment in **why** he/she is down voting the answer. I have absolutely no problem with being criticized ;). If it is due to the variable inside the SQL query, so be it. Security issues is completely out the scope of the OPs question.